# Universal property of the direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that the universal property of the direct product is not satisfied by the direct sum. That means I want to find a ring $R$, modules $M_i$ and $N$ and module homomorphisms $f_i:N\rightarrow M_i$ such that an $f:N\rightarrow\bigoplus_iM_i$ is not unique or does not exists.

I tried to choose $M_i=R=N=\mathbb{Z}$ but could not prove the claim. What can I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proof that direct sums and products are not necessarily isomorphic, without using the universal property: Direct sums and direct products are unique up to isomorphism. The direct sum $\oplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, but the direct product $\prod_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ is uncountable, so they are not isomorphic.

It is a little strange to try to prove that the universal property of direct sums is not satisfied by direct products, because a direct sum $\bigoplus_i M_i$ comes with *embeddings* $M_j\hookrightarrow\bigoplus_i M_i$, but a direct product $\prod_i M_i$ comes with *projections* $\prod_i M_i\twoheadrightarrow M_j$, so the arrows are in the opposite direction.

However, we do know the usual descriptions of direct sums and products, and there are usual embeddings $M_j\to\prod M_i$ (although I wouldn't call them canonical). If we consider **these** embeddings then we can look at a similar counter-example: Take $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. Take the identity $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$. By choosing an appropriate basis of $\prod\mathbb{Q}$, we can find two distinct morphisms $p_1,p_2:\prod\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ for which $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow\prod \mathbb{Q}\overset{p_i}{\to}\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity, so uniqueness is not satisfied.

Comment: Yes, this seems true. But I want to show this by showing that such a $f$ is not unique oder does not exist.

Comment: @user114179 See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get the point with the 'appropriate basis'. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @user114179 I was just lazy to write what kind of basis you want. You should take a basis containing elements of the form $x_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$, and something not in the span of these, say $y=(1,1,1,\ldots)$. Then extend this to some basis on $\prod\mathbb{Q}$, and take linear maps $p_1,p_2;\prod\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ with $p_i(x_j)=1$ and $p_i(y)=i$.

Comment: Thank you! Why can't we work with $\mathbb{Z}$ here? And if we claim 'universal property of the direct sum is not satisfied by the direct product', how would you do this?

Comment: @user114179 I used $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ because we have lots of morphisms on vector spaces. This isn'ot the case for $\mathbb{Z}$: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46475/infinite-direct-product-of-the-integers-not-a-free-module-over-the-integers. We could have used $\mathbb{Z}$ instead, but the argument would be more complicated. As for the second question, it's answered in the post (but I repeat: In principle this question doesn't make a lot of sense, although the question of "why it doesn't make sense", in my opinion, is completely valid. This is also explained in the post).